# Event on ItemsControl issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, itemscontrol

I defined an ItemsControl inside a grid, and in the ItemsControl.Resources, I defined 2 events for the child grid, *MouseEnter* and *MouseLeave*.

```
<Grid>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Colonnes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="StyleTableau">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="ColonneMouseEnter"/>
            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="ColonneMouseLeave"/>
        </Style>   
    </ItemsControl.Resources>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="vm:VueModeleColonnePQ">
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource StyleTableau}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
                    <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource StyleEllipseJ1}" Visibility="{Binding IsPionVisible, Converter={StaticResource boolConv}, ConverterParameter='visible.hidden'}"/>
                </Grid>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" >
                    <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource StyleEllipseVide}" Name="El0"/>
                    <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource StyleEllipseVide}" Name="El1"/>
                    <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource StyleEllipseVide}" Name="El2"/>
                    <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource StyleEllipseVide}" Name="El3"/>
                    <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource StyleEllipseVide}" Name="El4"/>
                    <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource StyleEllipseVide}" Name="El5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                    
</ItemsControl>
```

My issue is that events are fired, but when the Mouse Enter and Leave for each **Ellipse**, not for the parent Grid, and I don't know why.

Where did I fail ?

Thank you.

Comment: Add `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>` to the Grid Style.

Comment: @Clemens : It's working find ! Can you explain me why this is the solution ? Thank you.

Comment: UI elements do only receive mouse input in areas that are actually rendered with a non-null Brush. The default Background of a Grid null.

Comment: @Clemens Ok, thank you very much.